# htaccess mod Rewrite Rule - optional parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite the below:

1. http://www.mywebsite/address/12345/   to http://www.mywebsite/address/?param1=12345
2. http://www.mywebsite/address/12345/12 to http://www.mywebsite/address/?param1=12345&param2=12
3. http://www.mywebsite/address/12345/?{otherparam}=1 to http://www.mywebsite/address/?param1=12345&{otherparam}=1

Below is what I have in the .htaccess file.  I have the first two working fine but am struggling with the 3rd.  I need the third to pass param1 and also pass other optional parameters.   Can anyone assist?

```
RewriteRule ^address/([^/\.]+)/?$ address/?param1=$1  [NC]
RewriteRule ^address/([^/]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ address/?param1=$1&param2=$2  [NC]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `QSA` flag, which appends any existing query string to the newly constructed one in the rule's target:

```
RewriteRule ^address/([^/\.]+)/?$ address/?param1=$1  [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^address/([^/]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ address/?param1=$1&param2=$2  [NC,QSA,L]
```